# iOS 8.1.2 Remote Notification Issue When App Is In The Background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am having issues with processing push notifications in the background on iOS 8.1.2, specifically on the iPhone.

So basically, when I send a push notification to my iPad (running iOS 8.1.2), the method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` always gets called whether my app is running in the foreground or suspended in the background. However on my iPhone (also running iOS 8.1.2) the method only gets called when my app is in the foreground.

Has anyone experienced this problem before, or maybe know the solution?

FYI, my app already has the **remote-notifications background mode** enabled and I have added **content-available = 1** to the notification payload. I am also sending the push notifications on a production environment.

Comment: Have you checked the settings on your iPhone to make sure push notifications are allowed by the device? Sounds like a local settings issue to me.

Comment: @miken.mkndev Yes I have. As I mentioned, push notifications are being processed but only when the app is in the foreground. Weird thing is, this only occurs on iPhone devices. I tested on iPads running 8.1.2 and iOS 7-something and both work fine.

Comment: I have the same issue @DavidChang, any info how to fix that?